# Extracting Mac Addresses from Imported List

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to track down a bunch of MAC address based on the IEEE list. I have a list in separate sheets in an excel workbook. I also have a list of partial mac addresses in the last sheet from the IEEE that just includes the first 6 alphanumeric characters. I want to scan through all of the workbooks and, based on the search, create a separate sheet that just has the matching MAC Addresses. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: I can put all of them into one but I need them separate because of the rest of the content. It would be nice if it would create a new sheet or highlight the entire row.   I'm trying to match the last page that has a list of Apple MAC address to a list we have on the previous pages.

Comment: 0000.46
0003.93
0005.02
000A.27
000A.95
000D.93
0010.FA
0011.24
0013.D5
0014.51 These are mac addresses in rows on the last sheet of the workbook. I want to scan the all rows in the other sheets to see if they are found. If so, highlight the entire row.

Answer (score 0):

Far from a 'neat' answer (but more elegant probably means more difficult to explain) without much data to work from I'd suggest:

1. Add a column in each 'separate' sheet with just the six digits you are trying to match (say C).
2. Name the range (say list) containing the MAC addresses from sheet 'last'.
3. For each sheet in turn, select `C1` and enter `=MATCH(C1,List,0)>0` in Conditional Formatting, select formatting and Applies to `=A:C`.